# Azure Function TimerTrigger Singleton Lock - Can It Be File Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Can I configure an Azure Function TimerTrigger Singleton lock to use Cloud File Storage instead of Cloud Blob Storage and if so, how? i.e. to take a "lease"/lock on a Cloud File instead of a Blob ?

And if that is not possible, can I turn off the Singleton lock altogether somehow ? i.e. to get the TimerTrigger to have no lock at all.

Unfortunately our Azure Storage has not been created with any Blob Storage, only File Storage.

Alternative suggestions to using a TimerTrigger also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I afraid that you can't disable Singletone lock for `TimerTrigger`.

Please see implementation of TimerListener here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Listener/TimerListener.cs

```
[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
    internal sealed partial class TimerListener : IListener
    {
```